# Avoid double search or unecessary construction with std::unordered_map (and others)

Tags: c++, c++14

I would like to find a element with a key on a `std::unordered_map`, or insert it if it does not yet exist.

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace):

> std::unordered_map::emplace
>
> Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.
>
> ...
>
> The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately.
>
> ...
>
> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element, or the already-existing element if no insertion happened, and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place. True for Insertion, False for No Insertion.

I've tested it, for my environments, and it actually constructs the element even if the same key already exists.

This can be a major performance issue.

From c++17 there is `try_emplace` that avoids this construction if insertion does not take place.

I'm limited to c++14 and after looking around I find two alternatives for the same behavior:

- use `std::unordered_map::find` first, and if the element does not exist then use `std::unordered_map::emplace`. If **key does not exist** I pay for a **redundant container search**.
- use `std::unordered_map::emplace`. If **key exist** I pay for a **unnecessary object construction and destruction**.

Is my assumption correct that I have to decide on this trade-off until C++17?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is my assumption correct that I have to decide on this trade-off until C++17?

Yes.

Or, you can use a container outside of the standard library that supports a `try_emplace` operation or equivalent.

Comment: Indeed, this is the very reason `try_emplace` was added.